# C++ inheritance Base class uses member of derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Is it possible to have a base class that has an instance of the derived class as a parameter to one of the base class's functions? For example:

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo(B b[]);
};
Class B: public A
{
  void foo(B b[]);
};
```

Is this legal? Also class A will need to include the header file for class B, is this problematic as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible with a forward declaration:

```
class B;
class A
{
  virtual void foo(B b[]);
};
Class B: public A
{
  void foo(B b[]);
};
```

but **it's a major code smell**. Please state what you're trying to achieve, this looks like a faulty design.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the curiously recurring template pattern:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(T t[]);
};

class B: public A<B>
{
public:
    void foo(B b[]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to define an interface class that defines the functionality you want to expose in the derived class.  If you want to access derived class B internals in the base class's member function then this approach is no better than the one already posted.

```
class IntfB
{
  public:
    virtual void meth1() = 0;
    virtual void meth2() = 0;
};

class A
{
  public:
    virtual void foo(IntfB b[]);
};

class B : public A, public IntfB
{
  public:
    virtual void meth1();
    virtual void meth2();
};
```